# How to configure existing Apache 2 server to use PHP?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, httpd.conf

There are a lot of posts on the internet explaining how to configure a LAMP environment but there are very few articles describing how to configure an existing Apache server to use PHP, considering that Apache is already installed at another location then the default one.

Such a scenario I encountered in the case of an AWS Lightsail Node.js stack which came with Apache installed but no PHP module configured.

Does anyone have any idea how to configure an existing Apache installation to work with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I've found the necessary steps to do the configuration (for Ubuntu):

1. Run `sudo apt-get update` to get the newest list of available software packages
2. Install PHP by runing:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
```

3. Run `sudo find / -name libphp*` to get the location of the `libphpX.X.so` file
4. Copy the `libphpX.X.so` file into the Apache `modules` folder
5. Open the Apache `httpd.conf` file and add at the end the following lines:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    ​SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
​</FilesMatch>
```

6. Restart apache server